# Gridview not updating after removing row from linkbutton within an updatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a linkbutton in a gridview that when clicked will update the DB and should remove it from being visible in the gridview. This is also in an updatepanel. 
When clicking the linkbutton the DB is updated, however the gridview is never refreshed.
Both gridview and linkbuttons are dynamically generated.

Linkbuttons are created as follows:
'b' contains the unique id of the data in the row.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{     
        LinkButton lbRemove = new LinkButton();
        lbRemove.ID = "removeLink" + b;              
        lbRemove.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lbRemove_Click);
        lbRemove.Attributes.Add("onclick","return confirm('Are you sure?');");
        .......
        e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add((Control)lbRemove);
```

lbRemove_Click contains the method to update DB and call the griview to bind amd update the panel:

```
protected void lbRemove_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{                         
      removeFromUser(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));             
      loadGridviews(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currUserID"]));
      upnlUserDevices.Update();
```

i have tried creating a linkbutton outside of the gridview using the exact same properties as the one in the gridview. When clicked it calls the same method and it refreshes the gridviews, just not when being clicked from within the gridview itself.

Bit stuck on this one if you can help??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out how to make this work.

I need to set the linkbutton .CausesValidation = false

No expert on quite what this does, but it does fix my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems to be alright. I can only think of two suggestions:

1. Make sure your are doing the DataBind to the GridView at the end of the method loadGridViews()

   YourGridView.DataBind();
2. Make sure you are updating the right UpdatePanel after doing the binding:

   upnlUserDevices.Update(); // is upnlUserDevices the UpdatePanel that wraps your GridView?

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. the last line in the loadgridviews() is the databind
2. upnluserDevices is the panel that contains the gridview.
The strange thing is that if i create a link button outside the gridview (still in the update panel, that calls the same _click method) it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

put this `gridview` in update panel